# Is it possible to see Persian words by W3M?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, xterm, w3m

I use `Ubuntu 14.0.4` and some times, use `w3m` and `XTerm` as browser. I saw [`EastAsianWidth.txt`](https://github.com/tats/w3m/blob/master/libwc/EastAsianWidth.txt) which seems contains `Persian letters`. So I expect `w3m` will show `Persian` words. Also this is `Charset Settings` of `w3m`:

[image]

As you can see, value of display charset is  `Unicode (UTF-8)`. But I can not see `Persian` words. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is shown in image which is described in question, `w3m` can show `Farsi` words, but I had to enable `XTerm` to show them. I found a way to do that [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1451241).

1. Installing [FriBiDi](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libfribidi-dev) package which is a BiDi algorithm implementation for Hebrew and/or Arabic languages. This package contains the header files and static libraries for the FriBidi C library.

   sudo apt-get install libfribidi0 libfribidi-dev
2. Download & install `bicon` package:
   https://launchpad.net/~behnam/+archive/ppa/+build/574785/+files/bicon_0.2.0-1ubuntu0~ppa4_i386.deb for 32 bit
   https://launchpad.net/~behnam/+archive/ppa/+build/574789/+files/bicon_0.2.0-1ubuntu0~ppa4_amd64.deb for amd-64 bit
3. running this code in that, in each session:

   /usr/bin/bicon.bin
4. Add the following line to the end of `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop` file (For automatically running `bicon` by running `XTerm` from Applications):

   Terminal=true
   Exec=/usr/bin/bicon.bin

Also I use `DejaVu Sans Mono` as font which can show `Farsi` letters:

```
xterm -fa 'DejaVu Sans Mono' -fs 20
```